# Is there a French equivalent for "wishing (something) away"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Is there a French idiom that can express, if only marginally, the semantic wealth implicit in the English phrasal verb *to wish away*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tant qu'équivalent potentiel, je proposerais *se remettre de quelque chose*.

> Ce fut difficile, mais nous nous en sommes remis.

Cela ne suggère pas une intention particulièrement volontaire de dépasser le stade du malaise, c'est implicitement un procédé progressif. Le souhait actif de *s'en remettre* peut s'exprimer par des moyens détournés.

> Je suis arrivé à m'en remettre.
>   J'essaye de m'en remettre.

Le sens est d'une certaine façon plus large en français, ça fonctionne pour n'importe quel état inhabituel.

> Ça y est, je suis enfin remis de mes émotions.

Mais ça ne fonctionne pas pour des objets ou des personnes. Quelques possibilités : *vouloir les oublier*, *préférer qu'ils disparaissent*, ou *souhaiter qu'ils n'aient jamais existé*.

Comment: Thank you. When you say _Je suis arrivé à m'en remettre_, _en_ is the equivalent of _d'il_ or _d'elle_, isn't it? So _en_ alludes to whatever I've been wishing away, doesn't it? Also, please read my last comment on the question about the idiom _taper [si] fort_.

Comment: Yes, *en* could mean “the impact of war”, for instance. Given that this thing is introduced by the preposition *de*, *en* is the standard pronoun used to refer to it.

Comment: s'en remettre is recover from something.  wish away is espérer que quelque chose disparaisse par la seule volonté.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not an equivalent short expression in French for all the cases.
Translation to French depends on the context.

Some possible translations for *to wish xxxxx away*:

- *espérer que xxxxx disparaisse par la seule force de la volonté* (ou *par la volonté seule*)
- *espérer que xxxxx finira par disparaître*
- *souhaiter que xxxxx n'ait jamais existé*
- *espérer que xxxxx se règle de lui-même*
- *conjurer par un simple souhait*
- *fermer les yeux*

<sub>Thanks to [Lambie](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9299/lambie) for feedback and translation propositions.

See also [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=125467) and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/english-french/search?query=wishing+something+away).</sub>

Comment: I disagree with your "No, this is an English expression". The meaning of all phrasal verbs can be translated into French. espérer que x disparaisse par la seule force de la volonté ou par la volonté seule. And you even translated it, and well: conjurer par un simple souhait.

Comment: Merci @Lambie pour ton aide. Tu as raison et j'ai rectifié ma réponse. En disant que c'était une expression spécifiquement anglaise, je voulais dire qu'il n'y avait pas une aussi courte expression en français qui puisse s'utiliser dans les différents contextes. Je pense que ma réponse est maintenant plus juste. Bonne année ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wish%20away) gives two definitions to *wish away*. I don't see any French idiom that corresponds to any of them.

> 1) "to wish away something" means to turn a blind eye on something, to forget it, to pretend as if you are not concerned by that and like everything is just fine , to ignore, to act as if it doesn't bother or harm you

To express this feeling, I would either use *ignorer* or *dénier*.

For example, *une telle douleur est trop forte pour simplement être ignorée* (*such a pain is too strong to just be wished away*).

Other example : *il déniait sa colère car il en avait honte* (*he was wishing away his anger as he was ashamed of it*).

> 2) "to wish something away" or "to wish away" sometimes means to detach oneself from reality and to fall into your own dreams, to dream a lot about something.

Even though this definition is clear, I can't find any relevant example. In French, I would be tempted to use "s'évader", but this sounds really context-dependent.

Comment: Thank you. So idiomland is quite an unpredictable realm to cross...

Comment: Indeed :) But who know, maybe someone will find a French idiom I simply forgot.